# py.test hangs after catching expected exception

Tags: python, pytest

I have a very simple test function that looks like this:

```
def test_timeout_connect():
    with pytest.raises(minus_one_rpc.TimeoutExpired):
        c = minus_one_rpc.Client("tcp://localhost:14247", recv_timeout = 100)
```

Without the `pytest.raises(...)`, I am getting a `FAILED` test with the expected exception.  However, when I try to test for the correct exception, py.test hangs at that test.

No fixtures are involved in this particular test, but it seems to have something to do with a teardown, since when I press Ctrl-C, the test is reported as `SUCCESS`!

```
test_minus_one_rpc.py::test_timeout_connect ^CPASSED

================================================== 27 tests deselected ==================================================
======================================== 1 passed, 27 deselected in 3.02 seconds ========================================
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Insert a pdb breakpoint and step through.

Comment: Thanks.  I already found http://stackoverflow.com/a/26634435/1235227 to be useful, but I am *deep* in py.test then, after ~20 "finish current functions", I am at "return report" from `call_and_report()`, and when I step once more, py.test hangs.  I should probably ask in the py.test issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: A destructor call that hangs.

My conclusion is that when I don't expect/catch the exception, the exc_info will hold references to the objects, preventing the destructor from running.

(In my case, I was using pyzmq with a timeout, but did not set the LINGER socket option, so the destruction of the pyzmq socket would wait for the nonexisting remote side to send something.)