# Docker file hangs python configuration step

Tags: docker

**Below Step hangs docker installation**

```
RUN cd /opt && yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel make -y && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz && tar xzf Python-3.6.1.tgz && cd Python-3.6.1 && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make altinstall && rm -rf rm /usr/src/Python-3.6.1.tgz
```

**Hangs here on executing the above command:**

```
/python -m test.regrtest --pgo || true
Run tests sequentially
0:00:00 [  1/405] test_grammar
0:00:00 [  2/405] test_opcodes
0:00:00 [  3/405] test_dict
0:00:00 [  4/405] test_builtin
0:00:01 [  5/405] test_exceptions
0:00:01 [  6/405] test_types
0:00:01 [  7/405] test_unittest
0:00:04 [  8/405] test_doctest
0:00:07 [  9/405] test_doctest2
.......
......
0:06:45 [187/405] test_itertools
0:06:52 [188/405] test_json
0:06:56 [189/405] test_keyword
0:06:57 [190/405] test_keywordonlyarg
0:06:58 [191/405] test_kqueue
0:06:58 [192/405] test_largefile -- test_kqueue skipped
0:06:59 [193/405] test_lib2to3
0:07:25 [194/405] test_linecache
0:07:25 [195/405] test_list
0:07:27 [196/405] test_listcomps
0:07:27 [197/405] test_locale
0:07:28 [198/405] test_logging  --- This line hangs its not moving next step
```

Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Why not just build your image `FROM python:3.6`?

Comment: maybe this topic will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350911/what-to-do-when-a-py-test-hangs-silently

Comment: yes @DavidMaze its python3.6

Comment: No, I mean, you can start your Dockerfile with `FROM python:3.6` and it will use the [Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) with Python pre-installed, so you don't have to build it from source.

Comment: its a application dockerfile in the dockerfile is the part of this command as i mentioned above from centos